# Change month in cakephp to 3 letter words

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having a problem with cakephp input type date.

How can I make December to `Dec`, January to `Jan` and so on?

I have this code:

```
$this->Form->input('Profile.birthday', array(
    'label' => '', 
    'dateFormat' => 'MDY', 
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 112, 
    'maxYear' => date('Y')
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dateformat option will allow you to configure the date parts.

```
Used to specify the format of the select inputs for a date-related set of inputs.
Valid values include ‘DMY’, ‘MDY’, ‘YMD’, and ‘NONE’.
[http://book.cakephp.org/view/203/options-dateFormat][1]
```

Comment: Hi Krishna, I am already using the dateFormat in my code, just that I am not sure how to use it and convert the Month to 3 letter words.

Comment: date format does not support 3 letters month format, You have to do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

use  css property

```
select {
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;  
    color: #4C4D51;   
    font: 14px "Franklin Gothic Book";
    text-overflow: "";
}
```